# Best way to match strings from different systems

Tags: c#, string, data-analysis, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-comparison

Suppose that I have a list of strings like this (the real dataset is far larger and contains other data too):

```cs
List<string> modelNames =
    [
        "XC60 Momentum Standard T6",
        "XC60 Inscription Standard T6",
        "XC60 R designStandard T6",
        "XC60 T5 Powershift",
        "XC60 D3 DRIVE MANUAL",
        "XC60 D3 GEARTRONIC",
        "XC60 D5 GEARTRONIC AWD",
        "XC60 T6 AWD GEARTRONIC",
        "XC60 T5  AWD R DESIGN",
        "XC60 D5 GEARTRONIC AWD R DESIGN",
        "XC60 T6 AWD GEARTRONIC R DESIGN",
    ];
```

And I'd like to get the closest match using strings like these:

```cs
"2.0 D4 Momentum Pro Auto AWD Euro 6 (s/s) 5dr"
"2.0 D4 Momentum Auto Euro 6 (s/s) 5dr"
"2.0 T5 SE Nav SUV 5dr Petrol Auto Euro 6 (s/s) (245 ps)"
"2.0h T8 Twin Engine 10.4kWh R-Design SUV 5dr Petrol Plug-in Hybrid Auto AWD Euro 6 (s/s) (390 ps)"
```

As you can see, the strings don't really match at all, but there are some aspects that match.

I'd like to produce some kind of confidence score. My thoughts were to break both sets of strings into words and see which one gets the highest number of word matches. I'm not sure whether this is the best way of doing this kind of analysis or what would be optimal and performant way to get it done in `c#`.

Perhaps there is a better way than trying to score the matches, like I described above?

I would be grateful for any thoughts, suggestions and pointers.

Thanks,

Kaine

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/feature23/StringSimilarity.NET

Comment: *"My thoughts were to break both sets of strings into words and see which one gets the highest number of word matches."* - you can calculate this using [tag:linq] after you split the sentence into list of tokens. though, i do curious if you are concerned with stuffs such as stopwords, unicode handling, and wholeslew of complexities in [IR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval). perhaps at some point you might want to consider an actual document indexing stuff.

Comment: @MarioVernari, thank you for this... It's quite a rabbit hole I've now found myself in. It's seems quite academic and I need to do more research to figure out which algorithm might suite me the best. Any pointers from you would be very welcome.

Comment: @BagusTesa, thank you for your input. I suspected that it wouldn't be as simple as I thought. I'm not sure how I would go about indexing the data, it will all be held in memory. I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: You gave us 4 strings as examples. What should those 4 strings match to?

Comment: @Kaine it depends on your need and tech at hand. if you have database involved you can leverage its full text capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

I made a test with your example strings. The result is not great. At most one word matches. I think that this is not enough to make a reliable match. Also, my solution has a **O(n<sup>2</sup>)** time complexity, which will not scale well if you have large sets.

Setup:

```cs
static List<string> modelNames =
[
    "XC60 Momentum Standard T6",
    "XC60 Inscription Standard T6",
    "XC60 R designStandard T6",
    "XC60 T5 Powershift",
    "XC60 D3 DRIVE MANUAL",
    "XC60 D3 GEARTRONIC",
    "XC60 D5 GEARTRONIC AWD",
    "XC60 T6 AWD GEARTRONIC",
    "XC60 T5  AWD R DESIGN",
    "XC60 D5 GEARTRONIC AWD R DESIGN",
    "XC60 T6 AWD GEARTRONIC R DESIGN",
];
static List<string> modelNames2 =
[
    "2.0 D4 Momentum Pro Auto AWD Euro 6 (s/s) 5dr",
    "2.0 D4 Momentum Auto Euro 6 (s/s) 5dr",
    "2.0 T5 SE Nav SUV 5dr Petrol Auto Euro 6 (s/s) (245 ps)",
    "2.0h T8 Twin Engine 10.4kWh R-Design SUV 5dr Petrol Plug-in Hybrid Auto AWD Euro 6 (s/s) (390 ps)"
];

static (string name, string[] words) GetWords(string sentence)
{
    return (sentence, sentence.Split());
}
```

Test:

```cs
var names1 = modelNames.Select(n => GetWords(n));
var names2 = modelNames2.Select(n => GetWords(n)).ToList();
foreach (var n1 in names1) {
    int bestCount = 0;
    List<string> bestMatches = [];
    foreach (var n2 in names2) {

        int count = n1.words
            .Intersect(n2.words, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            .Count();
        if (count > bestCount) {
            bestCount = count;
            bestMatches.Clear();
            bestMatches.Add(n2.name);
        } else if (count > 0 && count == bestCount) {
            bestMatches.Add(n2.name);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"{n1.name}  (count={bestCount})");
    foreach (var match in bestMatches) {
        Console.WriteLine($"    {match}");
    }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Prints:

```
XC60 Momentum Standard T6  (count=1)
    2.0 D4 Momentum Pro Auto AWD Euro 6 (s/s) 5dr
    2.0 D4 Momentum Auto Euro 6 (s/s) 5dr
XC60 Inscription Standard T6  (count=0)
XC60 R designStandard T6  (count=0)
XC60 T5 Powershift  (count=1)
    2.0 T5 SE Nav SUV 5dr Petrol Auto Euro 6 (s/s) (245 ps)
XC60 D3 DRIVE MANUAL  (count=0)
XC60 D3 GEARTRONIC  (count=0)
XC60 D5 GEARTRONIC AWD  (count=1)
    2.0 D4 Momentum Pro Auto AWD Euro 6 (s/s) 5dr
    2.0h T8 Twin Engine 10.4kWh R-Design SUV 5dr Petrol Plug-in Hybrid Auto AWD Euro 6 (s/s) (390 ps)
XC60 T6 AWD GEARTRONIC  (count=1)
    2.0 D4 Momentum Pro Auto AWD Euro 6 (s/s) 5dr
    2.0h T8 Twin Engine 10.4kWh R-Design SUV 5dr Petrol Plug-in Hybrid Auto AWD Euro 6 (s/s) (390 ps)
XC60 T5  AWD R DESIGN  (count=1)
    2.0 D4 Momentum Pro Auto AWD Euro 6 (s/s) 5dr
    2.0 T5 SE Nav SUV 5dr Petrol Auto Euro 6 (s/s) (245 ps)
    2.0h T8 Twin Engine 10.4kWh R-Design SUV 5dr Petrol Plug-in Hybrid Auto AWD Euro 6 (s/s) (390 ps)
XC60 D5 GEARTRONIC AWD R DESIGN  (count=1)
    2.0 D4 Momentum Pro Auto AWD Euro 6 (s/s) 5dr
    2.0h T8 Twin Engine 10.4kWh R-Design SUV 5dr Petrol Plug-in Hybrid Auto AWD Euro 6 (s/s) (390 ps)
XC60 T6 AWD GEARTRONIC R DESIGN  (count=1)
    2.0 D4 Momentum Pro Auto AWD Euro 6 (s/s) 5dr
    2.0h T8 Twin Engine 10.4kWh R-Design SUV 5dr Petrol Plug-in Hybrid Auto AWD Euro 6 (s/s) (390 ps)
```

Comment: Wo, thank you so much Oliver, I appreciate all the effort you went to. It's not going to be the greatest success in the world, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: I'm trying out the suggestion made by @MarioVernari, specifically the N-Gram algorithm, which has a cost of O(n*m). It's all a little academic for my needs, but the limited examples have a little similarity to my use case and they're all quite simple to implement. 

Usually, my matches are down to 2 or 3 examples in reality because I pre-filter the options (make, model, engine capacity, body style), so I'll work with that for the time being. 

It would be great to have some insight into have to interpret the pros & cons of each algorithm without having to read the academic papers though...

Comment: The outcome of these algorithms depends very much on the specific data. Therefore, you will have to make tests to see which one fits best. My algorithm also has O(m*n).